# How to scan a folder for unused images Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder of images.
I want to read all images and do some processing.
But next time if I run the script again, it should not consider already processed image, only new one.

What is the conventional way to do this?

Comment: Keep a list of the already processed images "somewhere"?

Comment: So I have to create a file(e.g. json) to keep track of it. This seems to be a good way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use sqlite to store data about already know files https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html
Later you could expanse the idea and use SQL to get bigger goals as "when it was processed" "what command you used to process"